# Display products exactly below the categories to which they belong

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to create a "php-mysql" system, where admin can create categories and products.

products would be stored at the categories they belong dynamically and at the user interface those products would be displayed exactly below the categories to which they belong .

For example: Right now my products are displayed like the following image:

[image]

I wanted them to be displayed like the following image :

[image]

My mysql tables are :

[image]

My codes(sql) so far are :

```
<?php
    function getCategory() {
        $db_conn = getConnection();
        if (!$db_conn) return false;

        $sql = "SELECT category from products";
        $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
        $db_conn->close();
        return $result;
    }

    function getProduct() {
        $db_conn = getConnection();
        if (!$db_conn) return false;

        $sql = "SELECT * from products";
        $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
        $db_conn->close();
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

PHP code:

```
<div class="category">
    <?php $categories = getCategory(); ?>
    <?php while ($category = $categories->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h2>
    <div class="products">
        <?php $products = getProduct(); ?>
        <?php while ($product = $products->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $category['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $category['image']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $category['price']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: why `getCategory()` returns always `false`?

Comment: simply pass the current category to the second function in order to fetch all related products.

Comment: for first command "if not connected to database", but 2nd false is my mistake , i am correcting now :)

Comment: can you please show me in code how can I pass current category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display all the products per category, you need to pass the category name when fetching the products with your second function:

```
<?php
    function getCategory() {
        $db_conn = getConnection();
        if (!$db_conn) return false;

        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category from products";
        $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }

    function getProduct($category) {
        $db_conn = getConnection();
        if (!$db_conn) return false;

        $sql = "SELECT * from products WHERE category = '" . $category . "'";
        $result = $db_conn->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
<?php $categories = getCategory(); ?>
<?php while ($category = $categories->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <div class="category">
        <h2><?php echo $category['name']; ?></h2>
        <div class="products">
            <?php $products = getProduct($category['name']); ?>
            <table>
                <?php while ($product = $products->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Still, you only need one query

Comment: @Strawberry, totally agree, but in general I don't want to change the OP approach as these functions could be re-used somewhere else.

Comment: it's giving error - "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in... " possibly I made error somewhere , I am checking my codes again ..

Comment: ok I got it ! thanks for your kind help sir , i was searching it for 10/12 days lol ..Thanks a lot

Comment: @mitkosoft , one more problem - categories are repeating as much as product numbers, how can i stop this loop

Comment: @Shishir, see the SQL in first function: ‘SELECT DISTINCT’

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY category`

Then just check if the category has changed since the last record you output, if it has, display the category name, if not, echo the record.

You shouldn't need that first query either if you do it like this.

The alternative is, keep the first query, but change the second to this:

```
'SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = ' . $category
```

where category is from your first query.

Comment: it's giving error "Notice: Undefined variable: category .... "

Comment: replace `$category` in my example code with `$product['category']`, obviously